When sharing a Mac word document using the sharing option, word automatically saved a local copy. How can I disable this feature
When I try to use the share button on the top right corner of the Word document to share some temporary Word files, it automatically saves a copy to my local hard drive, which causes problems for me because when I try to spotlight search a file by typing file names, multiple files will appear including those temporary files automatically created. How can I disable this function or get around it? I am using Word on a Macbook, not sure if this is also a feature in Windows.



You can’t; This is how editing a shared document works. Each editor will edit their local copy and the differences will be merged into the online document incrementing the revision as necessary

I am not sure sharing is the right terminology to use here. But what I intended to do is simply to "send" a document via the share a copy (envoyer une copies) function. I have no intention that the receiver can edit the original file. (obviously,  they can edit their received files but no later merger is required in my user case)

You are literally describing shared editing.

"I have no intention that the receiver can edit the original file. " When you share your document with others, do not give them permission to edit.
